# Kotlin: Sort list by mutliple attributes

Tags: sorting, kotlin, collections, attributes, mapping

Let's say I have the following code:

```
val list = mutableListOf("abab", "abcd", "aaa")
list.sortBy { it.length } //result: [aaa, abab, abcd]
```

This sorts the list by the lengths of the Strings.

How do I break draws (2 Strings of the same length) by some other rule, lets say number of appearance of the char 'a'.
This way, one would have a hirarchy of comparison-rules: First length, then break draws by number of 'a', then maybe some other rule.

The function *sortBy* only receives a selector, which maps the elements to a comparable value, which is not capable for what I want to do I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sortWith` and a custom comparator

```
val list = mutableListOf("abab", "abcd", "aaa")
list.sortWith(compareBy(String::length).thenBy { it.count { char -> char == 'a'} })
```

Here you can see documentation for all functions that will help you create a new comparator:
[kotlin.comparisons](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/)

Comment: This is what I searched for. 1 improvement:  `compareBy(String::length, { it.count { c -> c == 'a' } })` works aswell, because comparyBy takes vararg functions that are considered after each other to break draws.